# BigDecimal Class Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program for school using the BigDecimal class. The program is an interest rate calculator and and the final output should be somethig like:

```
    Loan Amount: whatever loan amount is in dollars
    Interest Rate: as a percent
    Interest: amount of interest paid in dollars
    continue? Y/N:
```

The book isn't clear on how to code the BigDecimal class and I'm using Eclipse so any time I make a change I get an error which is confusing. 
Could someone look this over and set me in the right direction? I'm using Murach's Java SE6 and the book just isn't very helpful.

Thank you!

```
    import java.util.Scanner;           //import scanner
    import java.text.NumberFormat;      //import number format
    import java.math.*;                 //import math classes


    public class InterestCalculator     //create public class
    {

        public static void main(String[] args) 
            {
            Scanner calc = new Scanner(System.in);  //create scanner
            double LoanAmount, InterestRate, Interest; //declareLoanAmount,InterestRate, and Interest as double

            //welcome user to the Interest Rate Calculator
            System.out.println("Welcome to The Interest Rate Calculator");
            System.out.println();
            //perform choice calculations until choice isn't equal to "y" or "Y"
            String choice = "y";    
            while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                {

                //Get Loan Amount from user
                System.out.println("Enter Loan Amount: ");
                LoanAmount = calc.nextDouble();

                //Get Interest rate from user
                System.out.println("Enter Interest Rate: ");
                InterestRate = calc.nextDouble();

                BigDecimal decimalInterest = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(Interest));
                decimalInterest = decimalInterest.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                BigDecimal decimalInterestRate = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(InterestRate));
                decimalInterestRate = decimalInterestRate.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

                //calculate interest



                System.out.println("message");


                //prompt user to continue?
                System.out.println("Continue? Y/N: ");
                choice = calc.next();
                System.out.println();



                }


        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm also having an issue with coding the calculation which should be something like Interest = LoanAmount*InterestRate and I know my print at the bottom will simply print the word "Message". In my earlier attempt I was trying to write a string that would print my entire output and I titled the string message.

Comment: I suggest that you have a look at the [BigDecimal javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) - it's pretty comprehensive. In general, `BigDecimal` is immutable, so you get a new instance every time you perform an operation. Like this: `BigDecimal someValue = decimalInterest.multiply(decimalInterestRate);` Apart from that, you don't need string conversions like `Double.toString(Interest)` - `BigDecimal` ctor accepts doubles and what not (have a look at the javadoc!)

Comment: I declared doubles at the top of the code. When I code the BigDecimal section they seem to not like that. But then if I change it up it will ask me to move it back to a double. I don't know enough about it to understand whats going on.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov `Double.toString(somedouble)` is the preferred way according to BigDecimals JavaDoc

Comment: Don't you lose all the benefits of avoiding float rounding error when you do `new BigDecimal(Double.toString(InterestRate))`?  You should just get the `String` from the scanner instead of round tripping through `double`.

Comment: @Mike. The book "Murachs Java SE6" actually shows to use the method I coded. Their example (on page 117) is an invoice application and it's taking a subtotal and applying a discount. 
What your saying makes sense from what I have read but because they don't show any other way to code it I found myself very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is related to this point

```
BigDecimal decimalInterest = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(Interest));
```

The variable Interest is not initalized at this point.

Something like this should do the job(however i did not improve your coding style):

```
        BigDecimal decimalInterestRate = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(InterestRate));
        decimalInterestRate = decimalInterestRate.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        BigDecimal decimalLoanAmount = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(LoanAmount));
        decimalLoanAmount = decimalLoanAmount.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        // calculate interest
        BigDecimal Interest = decimalInterestRate.multiply(decimalLoanAmount);

        System.out.println("Interest:" + Interest);
```

P.S. you need to remove the `Interest` declaration at the very beginning of your main method.

Comment: I appologize for my ignorance. could you elaborate on what I need to do to initialize that?

Comment: @JeremyBorton i added an example.

Comment: Thank you! I should be able to code the rest of my output now using the NumberFormat correct?

Comment: just to answer my own question it worked with the NumberFormat. Thanks again!